# What is the force corresponding to Lamor's formula for EM radiated power?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

The rate at which electromagnetic energy is radiated is given by [Lamor's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula). What is the corresponding rate at which momentum is radiated and hence force to this?

Answer (score 2):

The [Abraham-Lorentz-Dirac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force#Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz%E2%80%93Dirac_force) radiation reaction [four-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force) on an arbitrarily moving point charge of mass $m$ and charge $q$, due to radiated momentum, is, according to Dirac,

$$F_\mu^\text{rad}=\frac{\mu_0q^2}{6\pi mc}\left[\frac{d^2p_\mu}{d\tau^2}-\frac{p_\mu}{m^2c^2}\left(\frac{dp_\nu}{d\tau}\frac{dp^\nu}{d\tau}\right)\right],$$

where $p^\mu$ is the particle’s four-momentum and $\tau$ is the proper time along its worldline.

Comment: Obvious now you've mentioned it. I was thinking of something using the retarded acceleration/momentum as with Lamor's formula.

Answer (score 0):

Larmor's formula isn't going to give you a force or momentum because it is a scalar equation telling you the total power radiated by an accelerated charge.

In order to know something about force/momentum you need to know the Poynting *vector* of the fields associated with the electromagnetic power, as a function of direction.

Comment: I'm after a formula for the rate of momentum radiated by an accelerated charge derived like Lamor's power formula from the fields.